# Issues in importing a solution having Processes to create tasks which are assigned to a Team

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

Following is the exact scenario in my CRM instance.

I have a source instance, where I have created a solution which contains processes. 
This processes create Tasks records where the owner is set to a Team.
As we cannot include Team within the solution, and cannot export them, I have created team with same names in the target system.

Now I have exported the solution (in Managed mode) and imported in the target system.

Though the solution gets imported successfully, I get a following warning against task processes - "This process contains errors and cannot be activated. Open the process, correct any errors, and try again."

I can see the processes in "Draft" state in the solution, and as it is a managed solution I cannot open them to see.

Also, the Import logs are not of any help for this issue.

Can anyone please suggest what could be the reason here, and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processes in your solution contain references to the Team in your source instance. This reference is the guid (not name) of the team record.

Your target system doesn't contain a team with the same guid. You say you've created teams with the same names in the target but this won't help - it needs to have the same guid. Because the process can't find a team with the matching guid, it won't activate.

I would suggest you delete the teams in your target and recreate with the same guid. You won't be able to do this with the GUI (as it doesn't allow you to specify the guid). You'll need to either write an app to do it or use a data tool (eg, Kingswaysoft or Scribe) to do it.